# How do I collapse all folders in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a key shortcut or a IntelliJ IDEA plugin that will let me collapse all folders in the "Project" view in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The action is called `Collapse All` and the default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad -</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> on Mac (the project view has to be focused).

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer.

Comment: Is there a mouse shortcut like alt+click?

Comment: `cmd + -` on macOS.

Comment: Doesn't look like you need Control in version 18.  Just Numpad + and Numpad * will do the trick.  Focus must be on project window

Comment: Is there a button I can press to do that? I don't want a shortcut

Comment: @ACV sure, you can use custom toolbar or menu buttons. just add a "collapse all" action, see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html

Comment: Same default command works in PyCharm on Windows (they're both made by JetBrains)

Comment: If the project view is not in focus then `⌘` `1` to focus on the project view first, afterwards `⌘` `-` to collapse.