# Automatic collapsing of expanded folders in IntelliJ IDEA with auto navigation from source to project tree

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, project-explorer

I have set automatic navigation from selected source file to the tree file view in project explorer. That works perfectly :) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416111/how-to-automatically-navigate-to-the-current-class-in-intellij-idea-project-tool) for how to)

Now, after I open several files scattered in different locations of project file tree, this auto-navigation results in much too many expanded file locations. 
This is because every time I click a file, IntelliJ navigates me to see where the file is located, but when I click another, the previous expanded tree does not collapse.
The situation becomes 'blind' and I am forced to close auto expanded locations manually.

I need IntelliJ to  collapse those trees, that were automatically expanded, but leave those, that I have open manually.

In this manner I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540334/how-do-i-collapse-all-folders-in-intellij-idea), but its not exactly what I suggest.

Presumably, this is too fine feature and I did not see it in other IDEs. However, I believe it could help developers, especially in case of rather large projects, they are trying to dive in with little knowledge.

Comment: Request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanx. I will consider posting a request ...